# How to convert proc sql case satement code to Data step

Tags: sas

I have following code in proc SQL and I want to move my case statement to data step.

```
    Proc SQL;
    select 
    Xas,
    Yas,
case when missing(prj_role_desc) eq 1 then 'Unknown' else prj_role_desc end as prj_role_desc,
    case when job_descr eq 'X' or project_status in ('Open', 'Filled', 'Pending') then 'TB'end as tb_status
    from employee;
    quit;
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: IF/THEN statements or a SELECT statement. https://video.sas.com/detail/video/4573016759001/performing-conditional-logic-in-sas?autoStart=true&q=conditional

Comment: there are options to mimic `select` - `keep=`. `case when` statements can be converted to `if elseif` statements. [refer](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202239.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two case statements.

```
    data pies;
      set employee;
      if missing(prj_role_desc) then prj_role_desc='Unknown';
      if job_descr eq 'X' or project_status in ('Open', 'Filled', 'Pending') 
        then  tb_status='TB'
      keep Xas Yas prj_role_desc tb_status;
    run;
```